# What is the meaning of group.nodeLocation in One simulator syntax?

Tags: simulation, dtn

I was reading some tutorial of One simulator. I got one syntax that is

group.nodeLocation = 100,100

As far as I know a group can have multiple nodes. Therefore, I am not clear what does it mean by group.nodeLocation. Which node location we are fixing by using this command.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which kind of movement models you use.

Setting `group.nodeLocation` is required for **StationaryMovement**, but for other **dynamic** movement modes (e.g., RandomWaypoint) is meaningless.

If you want to set multiple nodes **N** with different location, you should separate it into **N** groups.

---

In speaking of **adding static nodes in bulk**, use `MapRouterMovement` to simulate it. The static node can be regarded as the initioal coordination equals the destination coordination. For instance, 5 static nodes are defined as:

```
LINESTRING (100 100, 100.0 100.0) 
LINESTRING (200 200, 200.0 200.0)
LINESTRING (300 300, 300.0 300.0)
LINESTRING (400 400, 400.0 400.0)
LINESTRING (500 500, 500.0 500.0)
```

And the setting file like:

```
Group4.groupID = b
Group4.movementModel = MapRouteMovement #MapRouteMovement
Group4.routeFile = path/routFile.wkt    #routeFile
Group4.routeType = 2
Group4.nrofHosts = 5
Group4.waitTime = 0, 0
Group4.speed = 0, 0
```

BTW, don't forget to group the above coordinations as a map file, seeing below:

```
#settings.txt
MapBasedMovement.nrofMapFiles = 1
MapBasedMovement.mapFile1 = path/mapFile.wkt

#mapFile.wkt
LINESTRING (100 100, 200.0 200.0, 300 300, 400 400, 500.0 500.0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I want to place my nodes to different random location. Therefore, I was thinking how group.nodeLocation will help me since in group there can be several nodes. I dont know how to fix the locations of each individual nodes.

Comment: @user3678107 Use `MapRouterMovement` to add static nodes in bulk. For more info, please check the edited answer.